# How to set constraints on Horizontal line programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, ios-autolayout

How to set constraints on Horizontal line programmatically in Swift ? 
I set this line in "Try Again" button. So, please tell me how to set constraints on this line.

Code is :

```
let hrzLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 647, width: 265, height: 1))

hrzLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

self.view.addSubview(hrzLine)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDuB7.png)

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to achieve....even your attached images is not clear. Do you want to achieve the same result as in the image??

Comment: Which horizontal line are you talking about? Please be more clear.

Comment: the above white horizontal line hold on the bottom of screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the value of constants accordingly. and make sure you declare *hrzline.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints* before view.addSubview just like i did below

```
   let hrzline = UIView()
   hrzLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    hrzline.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(hrzLine)


    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: hrzline, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: hrzline, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 265))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: hrzline, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: yourTryAgainButton, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: hrzline, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
```